# Can't find CMake created executable file

Tags: cmake

I am new to Cmake, I was trying to build an executble program from a Fortran code using Cmake-GUI. As per the program instruction I created the Cmakelists.txt. I then launched the Cmake-GUI and nominated the source directory and binaries directory and then used the configure and generate options to create my executable file. Everything seemed to have ran ok. Howover, when I checked my bin folder the .exe file that i was hoping to find is nowhere to be seen, instead I have cmake_Install.cmake and Makefile in the binaries folder. I opened these file with a text editor and they seem to be script file. Can somebody please tell me what I should do with these files to create the executale file. or if this is a sign of the cmake build process failing.

Comment: If you have a Makefile can't you just run make?

Comment: When I run the "make" in the make directory, the computer does not recognise it. I am running cmake-gui in windows environment. I don't know if I installed all the software that i should have installed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know CMake for fortran, but cmake in general will create the makefiles / visual studio projects etc.  We cmake into a bin directory, then go in there and run make.  It doesn't build the source, it builds the make files.

Comment: Thanks Michael, however the make is not recognised by the computer. Is there more stuff that i should have installed when i was installing the cmake-gui?

Comment: what generator are you using for the project.  In CMake if you delete your cache, and re-make you first choose your generator.  Then cmake will verify that it can build using this generate.  Are there any errors in the CMAKE GUI?

Comment: @Abdinasir Ali - you need to use `nmake` instead, if you are compiling with MSVC. You may also need to run `vcvars.bat` to set environment variables.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me to the right direction. Running Mingw32-make.exe has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the source?

CMake just create the makefiles and projects structures to compile using a make tool. I don't know how to compile it for Fortran, but in Linux for a C++ project, I just have to open a terminal, go to the build folder (your bin folder) and run `make` or `make all` and it compile the whole project.

I think that your problem is that your project is not compiled, so there is not any binary files.